# Is class variable initialization from an imported module thread safe in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, thread-safety, class-variables

I am aware of the fact that class variables initialization happens at the time of the import. If that is the case, in the code below, does the class variable initialization of class `A` result in race conditions?

**`a.py`:**

```
class A:
    # Static code here...
    pass
```

**`b.py`:**

```
class B:
    def func(self):
        from a import A
```

**`c.py`:**

```
import threading
from b import B

b1 = B()
b2 = B()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=b1.func)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=b2.func)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

**Terminal:**

```
$ python c.py
```

Comment: The global interpreter lock makes it so that only 1 thread can execute python bytecode, and when the first one imports A, the second will find A already in the imported modules, so no race condition here.

Comment: maybe adding a sleep somewhere will drop the gil, and result in race condition, however if the gil is not dropped then there can be no race condition ... or some sort of IO operation that drops the gil.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I am aware of the GIL. But just GIL might not be sufficient here as GIL comes with a time limit.

Comment: I've reworded your question title and fixed some formatting to make it clearer, hopefully someone knowledgeable enough in Python sees this and goes "interesting, let me check it out".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a thread lock on the C side in Cpython implementation of importlib, but just to be sure, I ran the following script:

imported file:

```py
import time
print('importing, in imported file')
time.sleep(2) # drop the GIL
print('finished importing, in imported file')
```

importing file:

```py
import threading

def import_other_file():
    print('going to import')
    import ex12
    print('finished importing')

t1 = threading.Thread(target=import_other_file)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=import_other_file)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

output:

```
going to import
going to import
importing, in imported file
finished importing, in imported file
finished importing
finished importing
```

> does the class variable initialization of class A result in race conditions?

so **NO**, there will be no race condition due to the lock on the C side.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no data race here (assuming you are using CPython or a similar implementation) due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock).  Only one thread can execute Python bytecode at any given time.

However *which* of the two threads actually ends up importing `A` first cannot (or at least should not) be relied upon.

Comment: I don't think that the fact that the GIL ensures only one thread executes bytecode at once is enough to guarantee no races here. Assume `class A: long list of statements`. Threads could be switched in the middle of some of the statements in the initialization of `A`, and the second thread could issue `import A from a` again while the first (now stopped) is still initializing `A`. Either some other additional locking is needed for module import or some atomic control variable is needed when importing to prevent a new import to proceed while another one is ongoing. GIL alone doesn't seem enough.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I remember from a distant memory that few internal python operations can defy GIL. Will ``import`` fall under that?

Comment: @m0hithreddy don't know enough about Python internals to answer that. If the `IMPORT_NAME` opcode is "atomic" then everything is fine, but I really doubt it is, as importing a module means executing an arbitrary amount of bytecode. There could however be some other locking/refcounting mechanism in place for `import` to be thread safe. You could test if `IMPORT_NAME` is atomic by putting an endless loop inside a module and importing it from a thread while another thread just prints something: if `IMPORT_NAME` is atomic and the first thread runs first, then the second one will never print.